# How to find the type of JSON object in java dynamically?

Tags: java, json, web-services

> {'sampleJSON': {'name':'john', 'city':'delhi', 'contact' :
>   ['abc.xyz@gmail.com', 9999999999 , {'city' : 'delhi','state' :
>   'delhi'}] } }

I have written a webservice in java which processes the above json object.

Here i have contact field which can be an array of contact details. 
To process it, what i did is

```
Object[] contact = getContact();

for(Object c : contact)
    { 

    if(c instanceof String)
    {
    //do some processing
    }


    else if(c instanceof Address)
    {
    //do some processing
    }

    else
    {
    //throw exception..invalid format for a contact detail.
    }
}
```

where Address is user defined class which contains the fields City and State.

Now my code is throwing exception even though I am sending data in correct way.

Is my approach is wrong ?

Comment: Read the exception stack trace, and print the type of `c`. Use your debugger.

Comment: Can you change the JSON to use an object instead of an array for the contact field? It makes everything simpler and you wouldn't need to check for types.

Comment: How are you binding JSON to object - are you using custom binding classes?  I.e., how do you go from address info in JSON to an "Address" object?